# Единая регистрация для нескольких сайтов

Tags: база-данных, пароль

Здравствуйте, очень хотелось бы узнать, как сделать так, чтобы несколько баз даных объединить в одну. То есть, у меня есть несколько сайтов, как сделать так, чтобы посетитель зарегистрировался одной регистрацией сразу на всех сайтах и в дальнейшем авторизировался одним паролем и логином сразу на всех сайтах. Подскажите, пожалуста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Возможные варианты.

- Выделяете один домен специально под авторизацию пользователей. При авторизации на всех сайтах осуществляете перенаправление на этот домен с данными пользователя (имя, пароль). В случае, когда пользователь ввел верные данные, возвращаете пользователя на исходный сайт с ключом, по которому авторизуете пользователя на сервере авторизации.
- Делаете вход по OpenID на всех сайтах, а провайдером выступает домен под авторизацию.